# Word denoting genetic state

Tags: genetics, gene-expression

Is there a single word, or brief phrase, that denotes the state of the total genetic machinery (genome + transcriptome + proteome + ...) of a cell or organ or organism at a particular point in time?

Comment: If you are including things like the proteome you are sort of tacitly including everything. In that case I would go with 'state'? I guess?

Comment: how about "Global profile" or "global expression profile" or the "omics state" or "omics profile"

Comment: @Bez I've heard people say "omics" at conferences, so that might be acceptable vernacular.

Comment: I think as long as you define what you mean initially, you could just say state.